# How to do row span group by in jquery dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am using JQuery and html. I have a table of list of data. The table shows building wise student info. I want to show the building at once in row span in dynamically. But i can't do this.

## My Problem as like

[image]

## I want solution as like

[image]

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-tablerow-groupby?file=index.js)

Please help me to find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: You can merge same `id` into one array then add `rowspan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data =
[{
        "id": 2,
        "buildingName": "Younus Khan Scholar's Garden",
        "studentId": "151-15-4366",
        "payMonth": "spring",
        "studentName": "Nahid",
        "semesterType": "TRI",
        "monthlyFee": 2500,
        "semesterTypeBooking": "TRI",
        "paidAmount": 10500,
        "endMonth": 12,
        "startMonth": 1,
        "regFee": 3000,
        "payable": 13000,
        "active": "True"
    },
     {
    "id": 2,
        "buildingName": "Younus Khan Scholar's Garden",
        "studentId": "151-15-4852",
        "payMonth": "summer",
        "studentName": "Aume",
        "semesterType": "TRI",
        "monthlyFee": 2500,
        "semesterTypeBooking": "TRI",
        "paidAmount": 3000,
        "endMonth": 12,
        "startMonth": 12,
        "regFee": 3000,
        "payable": 13000,
        "active": "True"
    },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "buildingName": "Younus Khan Scholar's Garden",
        "studentId": "151-15-5355",
        "payMonth": "fall",
        "studentName": "Ahsan",
        "semesterType": "BI",
        "monthlyFee": 2500,
        "semesterTypeBooking": "BI",
        "paidAmount": 3000,
        "endMonth": 12,
        "startMonth": 1,
        "regFee": 3000,
        "payable": 18000,
        "active": "True"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "buildingName": "Multipurpose Hall",
        "studentId": "151-15-4841",
        "payMonth": "spring",
        "studentName": "Farhan",
        "semesterType": "TRI",
        "monthlyFee": 2500,
        "semesterTypeBooking": "TRI",
        "paidAmount": 10500,
        "endMonth": 12,
        "startMonth": 1,
        "regFee": 3000,
        "payable": 13000,
        "active": "True"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "buildingName": "Multipurpose Hall",
        "studentId": "151-15-4930",
        "payMonth": "fall",
        "studentName": "Arefin",
        "semesterType": "BI",
        "monthlyFee": 2500,
        "semesterTypeBooking": "BI",
        "paidAmount": 33000,
        "endMonth": 12,
        "startMonth": 1,
        "regFee": 3000,
        "payable": 18000,
        "active": "True"
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
        "buildingName": "Female Hall",
        "studentId": "151-15-4564",
        "payMonth": "fall",
        "studentName": "Rahim",
        "semesterType": "BI",
        "monthlyFee": 2500,
        "semesterTypeBooking": "BI",
        "paidAmount": 3000,
        "endMonth": 12,
        "startMonth": 12,
        "regFee": 3000,
        "payable": 18000,
        "active": "True"
}];
 function loadGrid() {
            if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)){
                $('#fdDataTable tbody tr').remove();
                var html = "";
                $.each(data, function(i,data){
                    var payable = data.payable;
                    var paidAmount = data.paidAmount;
                    var due = payable - paidAmount;
                    html += "<tr >";
                    html += "<td class='build-name'><b>"+data.buildingName+"</b></td>";
                    html += "<td align='center'>"+data.studentId+"</td>";
                    html += "<td align='center'>"+data.studentName+"</td>";
                    html += "<td align='center'>"+payable+"</td>";
                    html += "<td align='center'>"+paidAmount+"</td>";
                    html += "<td align='center'>"+due+"</td>";
                    html += "<td align='center'>"+data.active+"</td>";
                });
                $("#fdDataTable tbody").append(html);
            }
    }
  $(document).ready(function () {
        loadGrid();
        var topMatchTd;
        var previousValue = "";
        var rowSpan = 1;
                $('.build-name').each(function(){

            if($(this).text() == previousValue)
            {
              rowSpan++;
              $(topMatchTd).attr('rowspan',rowSpan);
              $(this).remove();
            }
            else
            {
              topMatchTd = $(this);
              rowSpan = 1;
            }

            previousValue = $(this).text();
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="fdDataTable" border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- <th class="text-center">SL</th> -->
            <th class="text-center">Building</th>
            <th class="text-center">Student ID</th>
            <th class="text-center">Student Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Payable</th>
            <th class="text-center">Paid Amount</th>
            <th class="text-center">Due</th>
            <th class="text-center">Active</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```